# coordinate transormation

Tags: linear-transformations

In Einstein's "The Meaning of Relativity" I don't understand the relation between $b_να$ in equation (3a) and λ that pops up in equation (2b). I understand the fact that there's a linear transformation between the two coordinate systems and hence the form of (2b) equation. https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Meaning_of_Relativity/Lecture_1

Answer (score 0):

It just expresses the fact that the intervals are constant on their own,  so they must be proportional. The statement goes as

\begin{align}
\sum \Delta x_\nu^2 &= \text{const} \tag{2} \\
\sum \Delta {x'}_\nu^2 &= \text{const}' \tag{2a} 
\end{align}

Now write

$$
\text{const}' = \lambda ~\text{const} 
$$

for some constant $\lambda$. This is always possible to do if both constants are non-zero. Replacing this back into the original equations you get

$$
\underbrace{\sum \Delta {x'}_\nu^2}_{\text{const}} = \lambda \underbrace{\sum \Delta {x}_\nu^2}_{\text{const}'}
$$